# Unable to instantiate activity componentinfo RunTimeException

Tags: java, android, google-maps, runtimeexception

Update below:

I have this maps activity started when I click a button. I receive the below in the logcat. I have the activity added to the manifest. I have the setContentView inside the onCreate. I also have the permissions declared in the manifest. The layout xml is just a map fragment. Anyone see anything that might be the cause of this problem?

logcat:

```
10-09 23:16:10.516: W/dalvikvm(27281): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41955700)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.indeeditis/com.indeeditis.FinderActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    at android.location.GeocoderParams.<init>(GeocoderParams.java:50)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    at android.location.Geocoder.<init>(Geocoder.java:83)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    at android.location.Geocoder.<init>(Geocoder.java:95)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    at com.indeeditis.FinderActivity.<init>(FinderActivity.java:63)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
10-09 23:16:10.516: E/AndroidRuntime(27281):    ... 11 more
```

Activity:

```
public class FinderActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener  {

GoogleMap mMap;
Location myLocation;
EditText length;
String lengthString;
LocationManager locationmanager;
double lati;
double longi;
String nameFirst1;

   List<Address> address;
   Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_FIRSTNAME = "nameFirst";
private static final String TAG_LASTNAME = "nameLast";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "emailAddress";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "streetAddress";
private static final String TAG_STATE = "state";
private static final String TAG_ZIPCODE ="zipCode";
private static final String TAG_COMPANY ="company";
private static final String TAG_OTHERCOMPANY ="companyTwo";

private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
JSONArray contacts = null;

private static class LocationData {
     private double lat;
     private double longitude;
     private String name;
     private String other;

     public LocationData(double lat, double longitude, String name, String other) {
         this.lat = lat;
         this.longitude = longitude;
         this.name = name;
         this.other = other;
     }

     public void setLat(double lat) {
         this.lat = lat;
     }
     public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
         this.longitude = longitude;
     }
     public double getLat() {
         return lat;
     }
     public double getLongitude() {
         return longitude;
     }
     public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
        }
      public String getName() {
         return name;
         }
      public String getOther() {
         return other;
          }
     }

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maps);
    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    if (mMap!= null) {

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(17));

        }

    LocationManager locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria cr = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationmanager.getBestProvider(cr, true);
    Location location = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20, 0, (LocationListener) this);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng((new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))));

    new EndpointsTask().execute(FinderActivity.this);

}

public class EndpointsTask extends AsyncTask<Context, LocationData, Long> {

    private List<LocationData> locationList = new ArrayList<LocationData>();

    public Long doInBackground(Context... contexts) {

      Contactinfoendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Contactinfoendpoint.Builder(
          AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
          new JacksonFactory(),
          new HttpRequestInitializer() {
          public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { }
          });
  Contactinfoendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
  endpointBuilder).build();

  try {

    String apples = endpoint.listContactInfo().execute().toString();

    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(apples);

    JSONArray jsonArr = jObject.getJSONArray("items");

     for(int i =0 ; i<jsonArr.length() ;i++ ){
         JSONObject jsonObj1 = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);


                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String nameFirst1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME);
                    String nameLast1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_LASTNAME);
                    String emailAddress1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String streetAddress1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String state1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_STATE);
                    String zip1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_ZIPCODE);
                    String phone1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_PHONE);
                    String company1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_COMPANY);
                  //  String othercompany1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_OTHERCOMPANY);
                    String othercompany1 = String.valueOf(jsonObj1.optString(TAG_OTHERCOMPANY));

                    //test to see if made it to string
                    Log.d("YOUR_TAG", "First Name: " + nameFirst1 + " Last Name: " + nameLast1);

                    Log.d("nlltag", apples);

                    String whereDeyAt = streetAddress1 + " " + zip1;

                       address = coder.getFromLocationName(whereDeyAt,5);

                        Address location1 = address.get(0);

                        // SET LAT LNG VALUES FOR MARKER POINT

                    double lati = location1.getLatitude();
                        double longi = location1.getLongitude();

                        String otherinfo;
                        if (othercompany1==null) { otherinfo = company1 + ", " + " " + phone1;
                        }
                        else {otherinfo = company1 + ", "+ othercompany1 + " " + phone1; }

                         Log.d("Location", "Location:" + lati + " " +  longi);
                         LocationData data = new LocationData(lati, longi, nameFirst1 + " " + nameLast1,otherinfo );

                         locationList.add(data);
                         publishProgress(data);

     }

    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
      return (long) 0;

    }

    public   LocationData onProgressUpdate(LocationData data) {


        return data;
   }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        for(LocationData data : locationList){
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
             .position(new LatLng(data.getLat(), data.getLongitude()))
             .title(data.getName())
             .snippet(data.getOther()));
        }

    }

    }
```

Manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.indeeditis">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <permission android:name="com.indeeditis.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.indeeditis.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>

<permission
    android:name="com.indeeditis.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<!-- for card.io card scanning -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<!-- for most things, including card.io and paypal -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />


<!-- Camera features -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />

<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name="StartScreen"><intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
    <!-- 
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <category android:name="com.indeeditis"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
            <category android:name="com.indeeditis"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

  -->


    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".FinderActivity">  </activity>

    <service android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService" android:exported="false"/>

    <!--  paypal stuff -->

<activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity" />
<activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.LoginActivity" />
<activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentMethodActivity" />
<activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmActivity" />
<activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentCompletedActivity" />

<activity
android:name="io.card.payment.CardIOActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
<activity android:name="io.card.payment.DataEntryActivity" />

<activity android:name="Maps"></activity>

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyBqLKpJk50JUSkm_LYO_p079oqUr3qwert"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

**************UPDATE*****************************

As per @JonSkeet I have changed the 
      Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);

to 
      Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());

the logcat now reads:

```
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.indeeditis/com.indeeditis.FinderActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798):     at com.indeeditis.FinderActivity.<init>(FinderActivity.java:65)
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
10-15 22:45:50.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2798):     ... 11 more
```

I'm still getting a nullpointer but its not for the geocoder now.

Comment: What is line 63 on `FinderActivity`?

Comment: @Emmanuel List<Address> address;

Comment: Where is your class `Address` located ? In same activity file or you've created another java file for this ?

Comment: @shree202 All the Address is located inside the java file above.

Comment: Your code is horribly formatted please fix it..

Comment: Also when you are initializing the geocoder WHEN are you doing it? onCreate/onStart/etc. Your post as is is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I can work out the *problem* - but not a pleasant solution.

Your activity indirectly subclasses `ContextWrapper`, which overrides `getPackageName`. The `Geocoder` creates a `GeocoderParams` with the given context (`this` in your case) and that in turn asks the context for its package name.

Unfortunately, `ContextWrapper.getPackageName` is implemented by calling `getPackageName` on the context that it's wrapping - which is null in your case. As far as I can tell, That's why you're getting the `NullPointerException`.

You *could* override `getPackageName` yourself (in your activity). That would remove that particular exception, but it feels like an ugly solution. This looks like something that would always be a problem using this approach - is it the recommended approach in tutorials?

Looking at some other sample code, I think you may want to just change this:

```
Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
```

to:

```
private final Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
```

(The `private final` part is just a matter of good practice, and isn't part of the fix here.)

EDIT: It now looks like `getApplicationContext()` is failing for the same reason. It's possible (I'm not an Android dev) that anything context-specific is only available after the application has started. You might want to use this instead:

```
private Geocoder coder;

@Override public void onStart() {
    coder = new Geocoder(this);
}
```

Basically, you can only create a `Geocoder` when you've got a properly initialized context - so that's the thing to investigate.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I changed the Geocoder as you mentioned, but I am still getting a nullpointer although it doesn't mention the geocoder this time. I have the logcat posted at the very bottom. Thanks

Comment: @coconuts4eva: Okay, so it looks like it can't even fetch the application context. (Just looking at the stack trace - it's vital that you should be able to read this.) It's possible that you should only initialize this when the activity is started - you may have more context then.

Answer (score -1):

Package name looks suspicious `com.indeeditis/com.indeeditis.FinderActivity`. You can't have slashes in package name. Check your AndroidManifest.xml again.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. I think that's just the way the logcat writes, the package base and the entire package + activity.

Comment: This is called a ComponentName, and it perfectly fine.